# Reducing elements copy from vector to vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, reference, move

Say I have a function that accepts a `vector` of something is expensive to copy.

```cpp
void f(const std::vector<ExpensiveCopy>&) {
  // core
}
```

I want to extend it to a `vector` of `vector<ExpensiveCopy>`, which has a similar logic. For
the compatibility, I keep the original function.

```
void f(const std::vector<std::vector<ExpensiveCopy>>&) {
  // core
}

void f(const std::vector<ExpensiveCopy>& v) {
  std::vector<std::vector<ExpensiveCopy>> vec; 
  vec.emplace_back(v); // Oh no, copy here.
  f(vec);
}
```

I figured out a way that eliminates the copy by using move semantics since I make sure the argument is no longer used after passed.

```cpp
void f(std::vector<ExpensiveCopy>&& v) {
  std::vector<std::vector<ExpensiveCopy>> vec;
  vec.emplace_back(std::move(v)); // Ok, move here
  f(vec);
}
```

Then

```cpp
std::vector<ExpensiveCopy> v;
// f(v); // original
f(std::move(v));
```

**I am wondering is there any way that avoids changing the caller code?**

Comment: The caller has to opt-in for a `std::move` (or as I like to call it, "Go ahead and rip the guts out of this object, I'm done with it anyway.").  Because maybe the caller isn't actually done with the object.

Comment: If you are desperate, you can `const_cast` to a non-const reference, move into the vector of vectors, call the other function, and finally move back. This exhibits undefined behavior if the caller does actually pass a const vector.

Comment: "*I want to extend it to a vector of vector<ExpensiveCopy>, which has a similar logic.*" Does it have to be a `vector` of `vector<ExpensiveCopy>`? Or is a range of `vector<ExpensiveCopy>` sufficient?

Comment: Why not reverse the dependency?   At present, you *have* a working `f(const std::vector<ExpensiveCopy> &)` and, to "extend" it, you want to create a `f(const std::vector<std::vector<ExpensiveCopy> > &)` that implements the same logic as the original, and then call it with a modified `f(const std::vector<ExpensiveCopy> &)` that copies the argument into a `std::vector<std::vector<ExpensiveCopy> >` to pass.  Instead, why not leave the original `f(const std::vector<ExpensiveCopy> &)` alone, and call it from a newly created `f(const std::vector<std::vector<ExpensiveCopy>> &)`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 "*Does it have to ..*",  In some way, yes. I am not very clear what do you mean by "*a range of `vector`*". If it's something append all `vector` into a large `vector`, I don't think it will be helpful. I'll be glad if you can provide more hints or details.

Comment: @Peter Do you mean by copying the implementation? Doesn't it disable **DRY** principle?

Comment: No, I mean is it possible to implement the logic of `f(const std::vector<std::vector<ExpensiveCopy>> &)` by CALLING  `f(const std::vector<ExpensiveCopy> &)` without doing copies? For example, can you do something akin to `void f(const std::vector<std::vector<ExpensiveCopy>> &vec) {for (const auto &v : vec) f(v);}`? In any event, DRY is all well and good, but it is a GUIDELINE, not some inherently superior approach that always gives goodness. If a consequence of DRY is excessive runtime cost (say, due to unnecessary/expensive copying) then one justifiable option may be to not stick with DRY.

Comment: @Peter I see. Theoretically, I think it's possible. My example is a  much more simpler version of the real code. In the real code, the logic includes some other things that will not be done looply, like kind of initialization.  The reason I can call `vector<vector<ExpensiveCopy>>` in the `vector<ExpensiveCopy>` is a `vector` can be deemed as a `vector<vector<>>` with only one element, in some ways. Formally speaking, they are the similar. If I must do that, I can split the loop part and non-loop part, and maybe pass extra info(like index) . Umm, maybe possible, but looks much more complicated?

Comment: @Peter I totally agree DRY is just a **GUIDELINE**.  I believe in most cases, obey DRY is a wise choice. Although in some situations, where runtime performance comes first, you have to drop it.